# KIVY: Recycle View doesn't work when called from different class

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to work with recycleview but I can't understand why when I click the button "populate list" this works normally:

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


kv = """
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    Label:
        text: root.value

<Test>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    rv: rv
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(108)
        padding: dp(8)
        spacing: dp(16)
        Button:
            text: 'Populate list'
            on_press: root.populate()
        Button:
            text: 'Sort list'
            on_press: root.sort()
        Button:
            text: 'Clear list'
            on_press: root.clear()
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Insert new item'
                on_press: root.insert(new_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: new_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Update first item'
                on_press: root.update(update_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: update_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'new value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        Button:
            text: 'Remove first item'
            on_press: root.remove()

    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
        bar_width: dp(10)
        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: dp(2)
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class Test(BoxLayout):

    def populate(self):
        self.rv.data = [{'value': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6))}
                        for x in range(50)]

    def sort(self):
        self.rv.data = sorted(self.rv.data, key=lambda x: x['value'])

    def clear(self):
        self.rv.data = []

    def insert(self, value):
        self.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value or 'default value'})

    def update(self, value):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data[0]['value'] = value or 'default new value'
            self.rv.refresh_from_data()

    def remove(self):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data.pop(0)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

but when I try to do the same thing from a different class

like this, it doesn't work:

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


kv = """
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    Label:
        text: root.value

<Test>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    rv: rv
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(108)
        padding: dp(8)
        spacing: dp(16)
        Button:
            text: 'Populate list'
            on_press: root.populate()
        Button:
            text: 'Sort list'
            on_press: root.sort()
        Button:
            text: 'Clear list'
            on_press: root.clear()
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Insert new item'
                on_press: root.insert(new_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: new_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Update first item'
                on_press: root.update(update_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: update_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'new value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        Button:
            text: 'Remove first item'
            on_press: root.remove()

    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
        bar_width: dp(10)
        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: dp(2)
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class Caller(BoxLayout):
    def do(self):
        Test().rv.data = [{'value': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6))}
                        for x in range(50)]

class Test(BoxLayout):

    def populate(self):
        Caller().do()

    def sort(self):
        self.rv.data = sorted(self.rv.data, key=lambda x: x['value'])

    def clear(self):
        self.rv.data = []

    def insert(self, value):
        self.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value or 'default value'})

    def update(self, value):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data[0]['value'] = value or 'default new value'
            self.rv.refresh_from_data()

    def remove(self):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data.pop(0)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I searched a ton of posts on github and kivy docs as well as stack overflow but I can't find anything related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems with the second version of your code:

- Your `Caller` class is not used anywhere in your GUI.
- Your `populate()` method creates a new instance of `Caller`, but that instance is nowhere in your GUI.
- The `do()` method of `Caller` creates a new instance of `Test`, but that instance is nowhere in your GUI.

To get it to work correctly, just use the identical code as in your first version:

```
def populate(self):
    # Caller().do()
    self.rv.data = [{'value': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6))}
                    for x in range(50)]
```

But, if you need to do the `popuplate()` from a different class, you just need to access the `Test` instance that is in your GUI (not create a new instance):

```
class Caller(BoxLayout):
    def do(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.rv.data = [{'value': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6))}
                        for x in range(50)]
```

Comment: omg yes! I've been struggling with this for 1-2 days now.... that "App.get_running_app().root" was the solution. Thank you, have a great day!